# Fast build of a very large sparse matrix

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, scipy, sparse-matrix

How to speed up construction of a very large sparse matrix where each row has only one nonzero element in correspondence of a column and each column has an equal number (on average) of nonzero elements?

I have a huge (sparse) matrix of size `N1`-by-`N2`, say for example of size `1e8`-by-`5e4`, where each row contains only one nonzero element which is randomly chosen without replacement by `numpy.random.choice(numpy.arange(N2),size=N2,replace=False)`.

As far as I know, the only way I can build the matrix is to run `numpy.random.choice()` in a `for` loop `N1` times. As `N1` is very large, to speed things up I am using `scipy.weave`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import weave
from scipy.weave import converters
import scipy.sparse as sparse # Cython import

def weave_sparse(N1,N2,w):
    conn_matrix = sparse.dok_matrix((N1,N2))
    fac = lambda N : np.random.choice(np.arange(N), size=N, replace=False)[0]
    code = """
           int i;
           py::tuple arg(1);
           arg[0] = N2;
           for(i=0;i<N1;i++) conn_matrix[i,(int) fac.call(arg)] = w;
           """
    weave.inline(code,['conn_matrix','N1','N2', 'w', 'fac'],
                 compiler='gcc',extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11 -Ofast'],force=0)
    return conn_matrix
```

Still, for `N1` approaching `1e6` and beyond the code it taking too long to complete. I suspect that there could be a much more efficient way to build the sparse matrix. Any other strategy in mind to speed up and build the matrix in a human-readable time?

Comment: FYI: In the text of the question, you say `numpy.random.choice(numpy.arange(N2),size=N2,replace=False)`.  That is equivalent to `np.random.shuffle(np.arange(N2))` or `np.random.permutation(N2)`.  In the code you use `np.random.choice(np.arange(N), size=N, replace=True)[0]`.  That is equivalent to `np.random.randint(0, N)`.  (Why generate `size=N` and then take just the first element?)

Comment: @Warren Yep sorry. It should have been `False` in the code.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need `weave` to make this efficient.  Here's an example that should work for you.  I used small values of `N1` and `N2` to make it easy to inspect the result. I also used `csr_matrix`, but any of the scipy sparse matrix types should work with little or no changes.

```
In [50]: from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
```

`N1`, `N2` and the array `w` are basically the inputs; `w` is an array of length `N1`.  It holds the values that will be put in each row.  Here, I fill `w` with 1.

```
In [51]: N1 = 15

In [52]: N2 = 12

In [53]: w = np.empty(N1, dtype=int)

In [54]: w[:] = 1
```

Now create the `csr_matrix`:

```
In [55]: rows = np.arange(N1)

In [56]: cols = np.random.randint(0, N2, size=N1)

In [57]: conn_matrix = csr_matrix((w, (rows, cols)), shape=(N1, N2), dtype=int)
```

The `.A` attribute is just a shortcut for the `.toarray()` method; it returns a regular numpy array:

```
In [58]: conn_matrix.A
Out[58]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks @Warren. This is exactly the approach I was looking for. It put me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

So, the speed problem here can be recast as an efficient problem of building the very large sparse matrix. As @Warren pointed out `np.random.choice(np.arange(N2),size=N2,replace=False)` over all `N1` elements is still a random permutation problem. So, after some thoughts, a concise implementation for the above could ultimately be the following:

```
N1 = 10000000 #1e8
N2 = 5000
rows = np.arange(N1)
cols = (np.floor(np.random.permutation(N1)/float(N1)*N2)).astype(int) # Randomly pick N1 objects and assign to N2 categories in almost equal proportion
w = np.ones(N1)
conn_matrix = sparse.csr_matrix((w, (rows, cols)), shape=(N1, N2), dtype=int)
```